# Comma separated value search in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search this table with meta_value = '1,2'

How will I write the query?

Can I use `LIKE` ? I tried using `IN` clause.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ id ║  meta_val    ║ 210  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 1,2,3,4,5,6  ║ 5636 ║
║  2 ║ 1,2,3        ║  148 ║
║  3 ║ 1,2,3,4      ║  101 ║
║  4 ║ 1            ║  959 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Every time [normal forms are violated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), a seal puppy brutally dies. Normalise your schema.

Comment: Your use of ASCII art to draw that table is both awesome and disturbing.

Comment: @dvnrrs It is. Somebody was so terrified by it, they attempted to edit it out. Reject!

Comment: like '%1%' matches 13

Comment: Many of us will say this because it is important: You need to normalize your data.  That meta_val column should actually be a separate table with foreign keys back to the main table.

Comment: I want to do so but I can't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',meta_val) AND FIND_IN_SET('2', meta_val);
```

You should consider normalizing.

Comment: `s/consider/proceed with/g`

Comment: @Blazemonger :) world started considering RDBMS itself as obsolete!

Comment: @Blazemonger indeed . I have the feeling this is a wordpress issue :)

Comment: @aconrad You are exactly correct! I have no way to change the RDBMS. I   should get the result from this structure.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this method before, but it is both more efficient and manageable to create another table to link to this one using the ID's. Whether the data is inputted or not, it can be processed to use a separate table storage.

Otherwise you can use the find_in_set like aconrad has mentioned, or more preferably pull that data out from the database and process it externally if you must.