# MySQL columns with multiple choices?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering since I am new to using MySQL if there is actually a way to have on a table more than one option on a column and at the same time choose more than one.
Say that I am creating a video game table and certain titles are available on more than one platform (PC, PS3, XBox, and so on) is there a way to have a column called platform on the table and have the possibility to choose more than one of the options?
EDIT: I already tried using ENUM but unless I overlooked something I cannot choose more than one option using that.
Thank you

Comment: You need to create a relational design.

Comment: What @FreshPrinceOfSO said, although you can also use the [SET type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TABLE Game (GameID, GameName, ...)
TABLE Platform (PlatformID, PlatformName, ...)
TABLE GamePlatform (GameID, PlatformID)
```

If a game #1 is available on platforms #2, #3, and #7, you will have records three records in table `GamePlatform`:

```
INSERT INTO GamePlatform(GameID, PlatformID) VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SET` to specify a list of values that can be combined.

However, this is generally considered poor table design, as it is difficult to join tables that use multi-valued columns. It's usually better to use a relation table for many-to-many relationships. Study database normalization to learn more about this.

Comment: That field of knowledge is called "database theory" and "the relational model". Date's "An Introduction to Database Systems" would be a good choice, but there are other sources, of course.

Answer (score 1):

there is a workaround for this. the disadvantage here is that you have to add a new table for this.

Step one : create a table `console` for all console types.

```
id | name
---------
1  |  PS3
2  |  Xbox
3  |  Wii
```

and a table where you can group it. Assume that game id1 is Mario Kart. And you can play it on PS3 and Xbox. Then you have the next.

```
id | gameId | consoleId
------------------------
1  |   1    |    2
2  |   1    |    1
```

where `gameId` is a FK to `game` table and `consoleId` is a FK to the `console` table.
The first column `id` is optional (not required).

Comment: It's more than a workaround. It's good design. That additional table is often called a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Answer (score 0):

You can create even a varchar type field and store numbers, separated by commans, (1,2,5,8) which you map to the actual platform names. Then you can use mysql's FIND_IN_SET to match specific numbers, like in [Comma separated value search in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164665/comma-separated-value-search-in-mysql/21164773#21164773)

Do **not** use this if you care about performance when your table will get big and/or want a proper table design.

Comment: Using comma-separated lists in a column is an anti-pattern. See the chapter named "Jaywalking" in the book [SQL Antipatterns](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557).

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, why would you do it as VARCHAR rather than SET?

Comment: @Barmar with SET, when you have a new item you will need to do ALTER TABLE. What would be the advantage of SET over VARCHAR ?

Comment: Good point. This is actually why you should use a many-to-many relation table, not any kind of multi-valued column.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add multiple option in a columns, but there is a disadvantage in doing so as you need to find the length of the value and using INSTR() and/or SUBSTR() to find the position (This is tedious and there may be problem along the way)

The better solution is to use junction table, many-to-many (m:n), by setting the Game_ID and Platform_ID as primary key in their own table.